# Show certain amount of div

Tags: jquery, events, show

I have this code `Math.min(someVariable, 500))` I also have some divs which I have hidden`(display:none)` My question is: How can I use the code above in correlation with the Jquery event `'show'`? I know how the event works but I dont know how to put two and two together.

So the `'show'` event should `show 'someVariable' or 500` of the divs. 
someVariable is a number (from 0 to a billion)

Comment: could you please also provide an example markup of one of such div? is each number a representative of a particular div?

Comment: @Daxcode Just a simple div `<div class="div">bla</div>` There is nothing special going on with the div

Comment: @Youss you say the show event? Do you mean the show method? You want do to something like $("#myDiv").show() and the change the text inside the myDiv to either 500 or someVariable?

Comment: @ Simon Edström I have about 500 of divs, I dont want to show them. I just want to show a certain amount. This amount is given by someVariable. So if someVariable = 29 Then only show the first 29 of the divs, with a limit to show of 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more information to solve your specific example, but let me try filling in some details for a more concrete solution.

I am going to assume you have a bunch of divs with ids like: "fieldDiv1", "fieldDiv2", etc that are all potentially hidden.  And you have a bunch of `<input type="text">` fields containing your 'someVariable' numbers, and these have ids like: "fieldValue1", "fieldValue2", etc.  So, in javascript you could call the following function to solve your problem:

```
setVisibility : function() {
   for(var i = 1; document.getElementById("fieldDiv" + i) != null; i++) {
      if(!$("#fieldDiv" + i).is(':hidden') && document.getElementById("fieldValue" + i).value < 500) {
          $("#fieldDiv" + i).hide();
      else if($("#fieldDiv" + i).is(':hidden') && document.getElementById("fieldValue" + i).value >= 500){
          $("#fieldDiv" + i).show();
      }
   }
},
```

I know I had to assume a lot there, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort. But I dont see someVariable..I dont have lots of input, only one with which you can send a query and then the script will send back a total number wcich is presented with someVariable. Hope this makes sence.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:lt` selector to show the first 500 ( is zero based). If there are less than 500 will show all, if there are more will only show 500

http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

```
     $('.someClass:lt(500)').show();
```

EDIT:  To use variable need to concatenate variable into selector string:

```
   $('.someClass:lt('+Math.min(someVariable, 500)+')').show();
```

Or `slice(startIndex,endIndex)` method to filter based on index values you want to display

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: I know how to do this, this is not problem. The problem is that if someVariable is exactly 428, I would like to show 428 of the divs. That is why I put the math. So could I do it like this? `$('.page2:lt(Math.min(someVariable, 500))').show();`(this doesnt work for me, maybe now you understand my problem)

Comment: OK..I added an editied version showing how to concatenate your variable

Comment: Thanks, The other answer comes closer to teh answer I was looking for